# App store Updates

Tags: macos

I am getting updates for an other account in my mac, I get updates for an account which is logged in a different mac. why will i get updates for an account which is not active on my mac. Can I disable it? Please suggest me something.

Answer (score 1):

The AppleID that is used to download an app from the App Store is permanently embedded in that instance of the application (on the machine it is downloaded to).  So if someone else downloaded an application on your Mac/iOS device, only their AppleID will be able to update it. The reverse is true also.

Options:
1.  Delete the application and reinstall it using your AppleID.
2.  Have the AppleID that was used to install it sign in to update it.
3.  Live with the annoyance of not being able to update it.